# How to handle SPA urls correctly in Golang?

Tags: go, next.js, go-echo

I am trying to embed and serve my frontend (nextjs with static export) with echo. I am currently using:

```golang
//go:embed all:frontend/out
var FrontendFS embed.FS

func BuildFrontendFS() http.FileSystem {
    build, err := fs.Sub(FrontendFS, "frontend/out")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return http.FS(build)
}

e := echo.New()

e.Use(middleware.StaticWithConfig(middleware.StaticConfig{
    Filesystem: BuildFrontendFS(),
    HTML5:      true,
}))

e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":1323"))
```

It works great however when I try to open a url like `localhost:1323/example` it routes back to `index.html`. The problem is that there is a page called `example.html` and I am expecting to see that page instead. If I call the url like `localhost:1323/example.html` it works.

Any ideas how I can solve this so that I can just use `localhost:1323/example` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an `./out` directory being referenced, so it looks like you're exporting to static HTML. If that's the case, enable the [`trailingSlash`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash) setting in your `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

`./example.html` will become `./example/index.html` after the export.

Comment: I wish I could up vote you more. Thank you!